# Visual Studio 2012 - how to make current selection the default option for startup project

Tags: visual-studio, settings

Everytime I create a solution with multiple projects I have to go to the properties of that solution and change the startup project to be the current selection. Is there a way to make this the default option selected?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *make* ***this*** *the default option*? You can always Right-Click the Project (not the solution) and choose "Set as Startup Project"

Comment: I want to achieve the following effect: I start a new instance of VS, I create a new blank solution, I right-click on it -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Startup Project and there I want to have the "Current selection" option to be selected. By default the single startup project is selected.

Comment: Is it really that often that you start a new solution? If I understand your problem correctly, it only occurs once every time you start a new solution, yes?

Comment: Yes, you have understood my problem correctly. And I do start new solutions relatively often now, because I am learning and I make exercises for each lesson in a separate solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TOOLS -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> then search in the right side of the menu for "For new solutions use the currently selected project as the startup project".